# Need help in react native in text section

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

'My question is about react native'
'I am trying to changing the color and fontsize Hello, world and Hello but its not changing,the code running fine.'
'''

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={[styles.Red,styles.One]}>Praveen</Text>
          <Text Style={[styles.White,styles.Two]}>
            Hello, World
            </Text>
            <Text H1>Hello</Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      Red: {
        color: '#F44336'
    
      },
      One: {
        fontSize : 80
      },
      White: {
        color : '#F44336'
      },
      Two: {
        fontSize : 80
      },
    });
```

'''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `Style` with a capital s instead of `style`, props are case sensitive so make sure that you're using the right naming

Code should look like this:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={[styles.Red,styles.One]}>Praveen</Text>
          <Text style={[styles.White,styles.Two]}>
            Hello, World
            </Text>
            <Text H1>Hello</Text>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      Red: {
        color: '#F44336'
    
      },
      One: {
        fontSize : 80
      },
      White: {
        color : '#F44336'
      },
      Two: {
        fontSize : 80
      },
    });
```